# How to get city name from google maps location?

Tags: google-maps, react-native, expo

I am trying to get the city name from what is returned by geocode but seem to not working in any way I've tried. Can anyone help me pleasE?

here is where I get the location data which returns an object with an array of region, street, city etc like this

This line:

```
<Text>Location: {this.state.locationResult}</Text>
```

Returns this

```
[{"region":"England","street":"Holborn street","city":"London"}]
```

I've tried with locationResult[0].city but still doesn't work.

Comment: Is not valid JSON because of `etc...` I didn't wanted to write all the response. I gave couple of values as example of what I get

Comment: as you can see there is `[{"thing":"one","thing":"two","thing":"three"}]`

Comment: I can't get it even with `locationResult["city"]`. I receive `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating `this.state.locationResult["city"]')`

Comment: Still not `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating this.state.locationResult[0]')`

Comment: Sorry my bad I was just copy pasting from the above error and forgot to change

Comment: If I use just `this.state.locationResult` everything is fine I get all details. region, street, city, country, postalCode, isoCountryCode and name

Answer (score 0):

Тry this:

```
let obj = this.state.locationResult;
<Text>Location: {obj[0].city}</Text>
```